# Accessing a Google BigQuery dataset from a PHP script running on a Google Compute VM instance

Tags: php, authorization, google-bigquery

I am attempting to access a BigQuery dataset from a PHP script running on a Google Compute VM instance - on which I have installed Bitnami's LAMP stack.

The dataset is owned by another party, but the party has given me a full ownership role to the dataset, using my email address. They have also given me a read role to another dataset, again using my email address.

My PHP script is intended to read data from the dataset tables to which I have been given read permission, massage that data, and write it to tables in the dataset to which I have been given the full ownership role.

I have spent many hours attempting to work out how to setup the correct authorisations, running everything under my email address as mentioned, but to date I am still getting errors of the "you do not have permission..." type either when trying to read data from one dataset or write it to the other.

The BigQuery datasets are not owned by me as mentioned, but I have been given both the Project ID and names of the datasets involved, and the owner of both has used my email address to set up the access permissions discussed above.

Has anyone a simple step-by-step guide as to how to achieve the above. Does the owner of the datasets need two do anything more than as already described? I am finding working through many pages of Google Help very confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need service account key file, that comes with a different email address. The service account email should be given permission and not your email. Actually both, because one is used by you to work on the UI, the other is on the app you develop.

I've included a full PHP example for you.

You need to setup the service account default credentials see lines with `putenv` and `useApplicationDefaultCredentials()`. This is a working code I have using the library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

You need to obtain your service account key file from the console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.13.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

**php file**

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;

$query="SELECT repository_url, 
       repository_has_downloads 
FROM   [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
LIMIT  10";
$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.dirname(__FILE__) . '/.ssh/dummyname-7f0004z148e1.json');//this can be created with other ENV mode server side
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$builder = new ServiceBuilder([
                'projectId' => 'edited',
        ]);

        $bigQuery = $builder->bigQuery();

        $job = $bigQuery->runQueryAsJob($query);
        $info=$job->info();
//      print_r($info);
//      exit;
        $queryResults = $job->queryResults();

        /*$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery(
            $query,
            ['useLegacySql' => true]);*/

        if ($queryResults->isComplete()) 
        {
            $i = 0;
            $rows = $queryResults->rows();

            foreach ($rows as $row) 
            {
                $i++;

                $result[$i] = $row;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception('The query failed to complete');
        }

        print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! Do I need to give my service account email address to the owner of the datasets (which he has shared with me but using my normal rather than service a/c email) and grant me new and admin access to his datasets using the service account rather than my normal one?

Comment: you should be able to create the service account on your portal using the link included in the post.

Comment: Hello Pentium10 - yes I have done this and setup the service account and downloaded a key file as per your very helpful instructions! When I try and use it (using your code) I am getting "Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "accessDenied", "message": "Access Denied: Dataset edited:edited: The user edited-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.create permission for dataset edited:edited." } ]. I'm still baffled!!

Comment: Do I need to provide the dataset owner with my service account "edited-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" email address in order that he can set sharing permissions using it?

Comment: yes sure, they need to add permissions to that user

Comment: Thanks very much - all solved! Nowhere in the Google Cloud docs did I find anything about the need to give the service account address to the real owner of a shared dataset!